# unity2d: Character moves in different speeds on different phones...(Deltatime?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have this little programm where my player bounces back and forth. His moving left looks like this:

```cs
if  ((runright == false) && (birdyDead == false)) 
{
    float currentposition = 0;
    currentposition = transform.position.x;

    Vector3 position = this.transform.position;
    position.x = currentposition - movespeed;
    this.transform.position = position;
    lookleft = true;            
}
```

I have noticed however, that depending on the phone that I am debugging my game on, the player moves with different speeds. In some extreme cases he is just WAY TOO QUICK. like uncontrollable quick...
I read that maybe I need to somehow multiply some value with time.deltatime which does something to the framerate so that no matter what phone i am using my player is always on the same speed.
Im guessing I need to do this to my jump function too, right?:

```cs
if (((Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && (didjump == false) && (birdyDead == false)))
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpPower), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    didjump = true;
    anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
}
```

Can you help me and show me what do to so that my player still moves the speed that I want it to, but delta time is in the game as well? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to multiply `movespeed * Time.deltaTime`, in order to update the position using a velocity of distance per seconds instead of distance per frame.

Comment: ok i did that and my player is now moving hella slow. should i now just increase the speed varibales?

Comment: Exactly. :) 4chars

Comment: okay by just increasing the speed values by like 1000 everything seems to work fine. ill check back with my phone and everything. for now i think u have done well thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please don't forget to tag the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: :) wasnt able to before at least like 10 min had passed. everything works awesome! that was a lot easier than i thought! thanks a dozen!